# performance: joining tables vs. large table with redundant data

Tags: sql, join

Lets say i have a bunch of products. Each product has and id, price, and long description made up of multiple paragraphs. Each product would also have multiple sku numbers that would represent different sizes and colors.

To clarify: product_id 1 has 3 skus, product_id 2 has 5 skus. All of the skus in product 1 share the same price and description. product 2 has a different price and description than product 1. All of product 2's skus share product 2's price and description.

I could have a large table with different records for each sku. The records would have redundant fields like the long description and price.

Or I could have two tables. One named "products" with product_id, price, and description. And one named "skus" with product_id, sku, color, and size. I would then join the tables on the product_id column.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM skus LEFT OUTER JOIN products ON skus.product_id=products.product_id WHERE color='green'";
```

or

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM master_table WHERE color='green'";
```

This is a dumbed down version of my setup. In the end there will be a lot more columns and a lot of products. Which method would have better performance?

So to be more specific: Let's say I want to LIKE search on the long_description column for all of the skus. I am trying to compare having one table that has 5000 long_description and 5000 skus vs OUTER JOINing two tables, one has 1000 long_description records and the other has 5000 skus.

Comment: In general, hypothetical "which will perform better" questions for SQL are impossible to answer.  There are too many variables and a LOT of it depends on usage.  Please ask a more specific question.  We need to know what kind of queries will be running, how often you are inserting vs selecting, index structure, concurrency, etc.

Comment: Performance doing what? Just listing everything? Updating product descriptions? Adding new SKUs?

Comment: Performance in terms of searching the table. Lets use the select/where color='green' example. Does having a table with 5,000 long descriptions where 1000 of them are distinct slow down a select query more than joining the two tables (one table only having 1000 long descriptions)?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the usage of those tables - in order to get a definitive answer you should do both and compare using representative data sets / system usage.

The normal approach is to only denormalise data in order to combat specific performance problems that you are having, so in this case my advice would be to default to joining across two tables and only denormalise to using a single table if you have a performance problem and find that denormalisation fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

`OLTP` normalized tables better

Join them at query, easier data manupulation and good response for short queries

`OLAP` denormalized tables better

Tables mostly dont change and good for long queries