# MySQL efficiency - 2 seperate tables or join

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a question about MySQL efficiency.

If I had 2 very large tables of data, which are similar in columns. And I need to display the data together, would it be better to combine the tables into 1 or use a join?

Bear in mind over time there could be millions of rows in each table, so combining would double the table size.

What is the best way to do this efficiency wise?

Is it worth separating the data?

Comment: Why you are separating them in two different tables when columns are similar ?

Comment: Because the data is slightly different. I'm just curious if joining 2 smaller tables is more efficient than trawling through millions of rows of data?

Comment: How about giving context to WHAT your database has.  Sometimes it might make sense, you might even get optimization ideas if the structures are poorly designed, redundancies, future considerations.  Since not posting actual data, maybe even edit your post and put your CREATE TABLE statements to SEE the differences.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the actual data. If the type of data is the same in both tables, put them together in one table.

MySQL is able to handle millions of rows. You should ask again when you are actually witnessing performance issues.

You mean "use a union"? By using join you add columns to the resultset, seems like you rather want to add rows.

Comment: I'm trying to think ahead and build the database in the most efficient way rather than wait until I have performance issues.

Comment: Without knowing the kind of data and application it is hard to predict issues though. Maybe you want to look into sharding to split your database onto different servers. https://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/scalability.html

Answer (score 0):

If your tables have good indexes and your join clause is on key values it will be better than having just 1 large-sized table.

Take a look to this post: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8184903/performance-joining-tables-vs-large-table-with-redundant-data](http://SQL%20performance%20join%20Vs%20large%20table)

As it said, there is no correct answer, but depends on your own test in both cases.